# Add many in Django Admin

Tags: python, django

In the models list view in Django admin, there is a button to add one model.  I would like to extend this a bit and be able to add multiple items at once.  My models are for images, and so it would be nice to be able to add multiple images at one time.

I've had success at creating custom fields within the individual model view, but don't know where to begin on the list view.  Can someone at least point me in the right direction?

EDIT:

I want to change this view, and add a button on the top right to "Add Multiple Images"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use [tabularinline or stackedinline](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/)
Assuming you have a model that has a set of images and a model for each image
(so e.g.

```
class Portfolio(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Image(models.Model):
   port = models.ForeignKey(Portolio)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   img = models.ImageField() # or however you're storing the image, e.g. as a URL,
```

You can then create in your admin.py

```
class ImageInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Image

class PortfolioAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        ImageInline,
    ]
```

(You can also specify extras, e.g. how many inline model forms to start with, but this should get you started, assuming this is what you meant)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it.  Its pretty complicated, but not that bad:

Step 1: alter `change_list_template` in your ModelsAdmin definition

```
class ImageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    change_list_template = 'admin/my_change_list.html'
    ...
```

Step 2: Copy and alter `change_list.html`

I added my new button here

```
<li>
  {% url cl.opts|admin_urlname:'add' as add_url %}
  <a href="{% add_preserved_filters add_url is_popup to_field %}" class="addlink">
    {% blocktrans with cl.opts.verbose_name as name %}Add {{ name }}{% endblocktrans %}
  </a>
</li>

<li>
   {% url cl.opts|admin_urlname:'addmany' as add_url %}
   <a href="{% add_preserved_filters add_url is_popup to_field %}" class="addlink">
   {% blocktrans with cl.opts.verbose_name as name %}Add Many{{ name }}{% endblocktrans %}
   </a>
</li>
```

Step 3: Add your new `Add Many` url to the model

```
def get_urls(self):
        from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

        def wrap(view):
            def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
            return update_wrapper(wrapper, view)

        info = self.model._meta.app_label, self.model._meta.model_name

        urlpatterns = patterns('',
                               # I added this!
            url(r'^addmany/$', wrap(self.add_multiple_view), name='%s_%s_addmany' % info),
            url(r'^$', wrap(self.changelist_view), name='%s_%s_changelist' % info),
            url(r'^add/$', wrap(self.add_view), name='%s_%s_add' % info),
            url(r'^(.+)/history/$', wrap(self.history_view), name='%s_%s_history' % info),
            url(r'^(.+)/delete/$', wrap(self.delete_view), name='%s_%s_delete' % info),
            url(r'^(.+)/$', wrap(self.change_view), name='%s_%s_change' % info),

        )
        return urlpatterns
```

Step 4:  Create your view def

```
def add_multiple_view(self, request):
        return TemplateResponse(request, 'admin/add_many.html', {}, current_app=self.admin_site.name)
```

Step 5: Create `add_many.html`